# constrained draggable should not trigger over() in droppable in this situation, but does

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a problem with jQueryUI's Drag and Drop.

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshgreifer/Y6KM9) shows behaviour I don't expect:   Even though the red box is constrained to the x axis, a droppable's over() handler is still getting called when the pointer enters it, rather than when the dragged element itself intersects it.

Is this a jQueryUI bug? If so, is there a workaround?

```
 $(function() {
     $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
         axis: 'x'  // Constrain drag
     });
    $( ".over" ).droppable({
      tolerance: 'intersect',  // Surely should not trigger "over()" unless dragged object itself is over the element??
      over: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "over!" );
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug... It looks like the over function is tied to the cursor and not the actual draggable element, seems to occur in a number of other instances as well...

I found a couple of possible workarounds:

- Add the [containment option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) to the draggable like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Y6KM9/2/)**

```
 $(function () {
     $("#draggable").draggable({
         axis: 'x',
         containment: 'parent'
     });
     $(".over").droppable({
         tolerance: 'intersect',
         over: function (event, ui) {
             $(this)
                 .find("p")
                 .html("over!");
         }
     });
 });
```

- Throw the whole thing into a [hover function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy) the draggable when its not being hovered:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Y6KM9/4/)**

```
$(function () {
    $("#draggable").hover(function () {
        $("#draggable").draggable({
            axis: 'x'
        });
        $(".over").droppable({
            tolerance: 'intersect',
            over: function (event, ui) {
                $(this)
                    .find("p")
                    .html("over!");
            }
        });
    }, function () {
        $("#draggable").draggable("destroy");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions -- I think there might be better workarounds or even a fix for this though.  I'll try your first workaround which in my case means calculating and creating an arbitrary container element on drag:start which includes unwanted elements.